# WCF UriTemplate with large query strings

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working with a rather large query string(~30+ parameters) and am trying to pass them to a WCF service I've setup.

I've run into a few issues specifically with the UriTemplate field. This service is setup to access a third party Api, so the query string may or may not contain all parameters. I'm curious if the best approach is to build a query string and pass that to the WCF service or to pass each parameter(and in some cases String.Empty) individually.

I've currently tried to dynamically build up a query string, however have hit a wall with either a 403 error when I try to pass the entire string( "?prm1=val&prm2=val" ) into the uritemplate of "ApiTool.jsp{query}", or I hit an invalid uritemplate response due to the fact I don't have name/value pairs listed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario. Can you post a simplified example?

Comment: Sure thing. Originally I was trying something along the lines of:

ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
UriTemplate = "TargetApi.jsp{query}"

I'd pass the custom built query string in full through this parameter. I didn't realize this may not be allowed until recently.

I've gone back and have done some refactoring(maybe for the best), ending up with the correct name value pairs in the query string:

UriTemplate = "TargetApi.jsp?key={key}&otherParam={otherParam}"

Although the second way is verbose due to the large number of variables, it seems necessary in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you'll need to list the parameters individually. Otherwise, UriTemplate will end up escaping things for you:

```
    var ut = new UriTemplate("Api.jsp{query}");
    var u = ut.BindByName(new Uri("http://localhost"), new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "query", "?param1=a&param2=b" } });
    Console.WriteLine(u); // http://localhost/Api.jsp%3Fparam1=a&param2=b
```

Comment: After getting deeper into this, I have to agree. It's a little cumbersome when dealing with a dynamic amount of paramaters(ie, param1, param2...paramN), but I haven't been able to see a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'unescape' querystring with IClientMessageInspector.

```
public class UriInspector: IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {

        // change/replace request.Headers.To Uri object;
        return null;
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) how to add this to your Endpoint object.